# How to configure Java 8 java.util.Optional using Spring 4 xml

Tags: java, spring, option-type

I am trying to configure using Spring XML configuration a java.land.Optional object using the factory method `Optional.of`.  However I keep getting an error.
I am using Spring 4 and Java 8.

```
<bean id="eventMapping" class="com.betfair.service.sogei.sem.dto.EventMapping">
    <constructor-arg name="sogTeam1Id" ref="sogTeam1Id"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sogTeam1Id" class="java.util.Optional" factory-method="of">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.Object" ref="team1Id"/>
</bean>

<bean id="team1Id" class="java.lang.Long">
    <constructor-arg value="1000"/>
</bean>
```

When I try to run a test I get an exception while spring tries to create the beans:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'eventMapping' defined in class path resource [test-data-provider.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.util.Optional]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [java.lang.Long] to required type [java.util.Optional]: Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.Long] to required type [java.util.Optional]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.Long] to required type [java.util.Optional]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

I have also tried:

```
<bean id="sogTeam1Id" class="java.util.Optional" factory-method="of">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.Object" value="1000"/>
</bean>
```

in which case I get the following (similar) error:

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'updateEventDatePayload' defined in class path resource [test-data-provider.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'eventMapping' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'eventMapping' defined in class path resource [test-data-provider.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.util.Optional]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Optional]: Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Optional]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Optional]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found`

The errors explain there is no way to convert the object Long to an object Optional but the method in question is this:

```
public static <T> Optional<T> of(T var0);
```

I want to have an Optional object containing a value that is a Long.

Has anyone come across this before please offer some insight?
Thanks!

Comment: I've long converted to JavaConfig, but I suspect the problem is using `constructor-arg` with something that's not a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in configuration of your "eventMapping" bean. You've specified there reference to "team1Id" instead of "Team1Id". "team1Id" in your configuration has type Long, so it should fail. Only "Team1Id" has type Optional. So you should use reference to this bean.

In general, I would suggest to avoid using beans with almost the same to prevent such collisions.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo.  Have amended it.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end this was the way I got it to work if anyone gets the same problem.  Through Spring expression language.

`<constructor-arg name="eventMapping" value="#{ T(java.util.Optional).of( 1)}"/>`

Could not get it to work using the factory-method="of" strategy.

It's easier to do it with Java configuration as noted above but in this case I was compelled to use xml config.

Hope that helps!